# How to send the query parameters as abc=123&dfc=34 to back end service in WSO2?

Tags: wso2-esb

```
   resource methods="POST GET OPTIONS DELETE PUT" uri-template="/{pattern}/data/{scope}/roles.json*">
        inSequence>
            property name="uri.var.pattern" expression="get-property('uri.var.pattern')"/>
            property name="uri.var.scope" expression="get-property('uri.var.scope')"/>
            property name="startIndex" expression="$ctx:query.param.abc"/>
            property name="count" expression="$ctx:query.param.dfc"/>
            property name="uri.var.counting" expression="fn:concat('abc=',$ctx:query.param.abc,'dfc=',$ctx:query.param.dfc)"/>
            filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
                then>
                    send>
                        endpoint name="admin--optional_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                            http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/ExistingService/{uri.var.pattern}/data/{uri.var.scope}/roles.json?{uri.var.counting}">
                                timeout>
                                    duration>30000
                                    responseAction>fault
                                /timeout>
                                suspendOnFailure>
                                    errorCodes>-1
                                    initialDuration>0
                                    progressionFactor>1.0
                                    maximumDuration>0
                                /suspendOnFailure>
                                markForSuspension>
                                    errorCodes>-1
                                /markForSuspension>
                            /http>
                        /endpoint>
                    /send>
                /then>
                else>
                    sequence key="_sandbox_key_error_"/>
                /else>
            /filter>
        /inSequence>
        outSequence>
            send/>
        /outSequence>
    /resource>
```

Comment: I want the url to be sent to as "/localhost:8080/ExistingService/file/data/test/roles.json?abc=123&dfc=34" but in turn the API manager is sending the url as "/localhost:8080/ExistingService/file/data/test/roles.json?abc%3D123dfc%#D34" please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the **question** in the body of your *question* by editing the post. You can then delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8081/ExistingService/{uri.var.pattern}/data/{uri.var.scope}/roles.json?abc={query.param.abc}&amp;dfc={query.param.dfc}"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

Or you can compose your own http request dynamically :

```
<property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<header name="To" expression="xxx"/>
<send/>
```

(use `<filter xpath="boolean(get-property('YYY'))">` to verify if a property exist)

Comment: Hi Jean I tried this way It works fine for two parameters but If I send only one parameter it is asking for the other parameter, so i want to make the query parameters as optional is there any way to make the query parameters as optional please help me......

Comment: Hi jean, do you mean to add multiple endpoints for corresponding query parameters.

Comment: If you compose your request dynamically, you don't need to define any endpoint : the send mediator will send a get request to the URL which litteral value is associated with the "To" Header. For exemple : <header name="To" value="http://localhost:8280/services/test"><send/> will send a Get HTTP to "http://localhost:8280/services/test"